# Jetpack Glance Widget: Scroll to specific item in LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-widget, glance-appwidget, glance

I have the widget that fetch and display the list of data via LazyColumn. After the data loaded, I want the LazyColumn to scroll to specific item.

In Jetpack Compose we have `LazyListState` but do we have something similar in Glance? (or any workaround)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with RemoteViews or app widgets framework, thus not possible with  Glance.

Given the way the framework is setup this would not be possible.

Note: widget should show a short list of data and bring user to the in-app experience for more